# How do we determine the lightning component is requesting from Mobile device or a Desktop?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, lightning, rendering

I have a Lightning Component which loads in both Mobile(SF1) and Desktop,
is there a way to detect the client(who is requesting Mobile or Desktop)
based on the parameter value I need to render some attributes inside the component.

How could I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: you can use javascript for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $Browser global value provider returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

Returns a FormFactor enum value based on the type of hardware the browser is running on.

1. DESKTOP for a desktop client
2. PHONE for a phone including a mobile phone with a browser and a smartphone
3. TABLET for a tablet client (for which isTablet returns true)

Ctrl

```
({
    checkBrowser: function(component) {
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        alert("You are using a " + device);
    }
})
```

Component

```
<aura:component>
        {!$Browser.isTablet}
        {!$Browser.isPhone}
        {!$Browser.isAndroid}
        {!$Browser.formFactor}
    </aura:component>
```

By using this way you can determine