# Mobile or Desktop User login

Tags: user, login, login-history

I did refer this link before posting the ask here

[How do we determine the lightning component is requesting from Mobile device or a Desktop?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101182/how-do-we-determine-the-lightning-component-is-requesting-from-mobile-device-or)

My **Partner community license users** access the experience site either from a custom mobile app (mobile sdk), desktop OR m-site

Iam interested in pulling out a report to list all these users grouped by source. Initially I thought LoginHistory would have all the information but does not look like it has.

Is there a standard way to capture this ?

Thanks,
MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try querying the Login History Object

```
/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=SELECT+ApiType,ApiVersion,Application,Browser,ClientVersion,Id,LoginTime,LoginType,LoginUrl,NetworkId,Platform,SourceIp,Status,UserId+FROM+LoginHistory
```

For the custom app built using Mobile SDK type:

- Browser = unknown
- LoginType = Oauth 2.0 or Remote Access 2.0

For web I would look into the Browser field as that I believe will have some value. I would also check for the Platform. For Desktop that would show MAC or Windows to confirm it is from Desktop. The login type for these would be `PrmPortal`